# Classification of Coverings of torus , $P^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I was reading chapter $12$ of John Lee's Book on Topological Manifolds.

> Let $X$ be a topological space that has a universal covering space, and let $x_0\in X$ be any base point. There is a one to one correspondence between isomorphism classes of coverings of $X$ and conjugacy classes of subgroups of $\pi_{1}(X,x_0)$. The correspondence associates each covering $\hat{q}:\hat{E} \rightarrow X$ with the conjugacy class of its induced subgroup.

So using this theorem we can classify the torus coverings. There are exactly three.

My question is the following:
do we have similar kind of classification theorem for coverings of $P^1$, If yes kindly mention the reference. If the problem is still not solved, what  is the progress made.

Comment: Number of coverings of the torus is not three. Fundamental group of $T^2$ is $\Bbb Z^2$ (which is abelian, so speaking of conjugacy classes of subgroups is not different from speaking directly of subgroups), nontrivial subgroups of which are of the form $n \Bbb Z \oplus m \Bbb Z$. There are infinitely many coverings of $\Bbb T^2$. For $\Bbb{RP}^1$, fundamental group is $\Bbb Z$ (it's homeomorphic to $S^1$), which also has infinitely many covers. If you're speaking of $\Bbb{CP}^1$, then as the answer below says: it's simply connected (homeomorphic to $S^2$) hence there's no nontrivial covers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, $\pi_1(\text{torus})  = \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ and there are infinitely many subgroups. So the number of isomorphic class of torus covering is not three.

On the other hand, $\mathbb P^1$ is simply connected (I assume you are talking about the complex projective space) so there is only one covering up to isomorphism, the trivial one.

Comment: I got your point. You are right . But sir if I take projective line over rationals then what happens.

Comment: The question you linked are about **branched** covering. Which is quite different from the covering we talk about here. @vikassrivastava

Comment: sir what is the difference between branched covering and "covering".  I means what is the basic difference.

Comment: covering is a topological concept, while to talk about branched covering we are talking about some Riemann surface. It is a topic in complex analysis/algebraic geometry. @vikassrivastava

Comment: SO It means In the question I linked they are treating $P^1$ as Riemann sphere(which is a Riemann surface). Actually Sir when I asked this question. I had the question that I linked, in my mind. I was thinking what are the other possible cover (I should say branch) of $P^1$. Is there any classification theorem for branched cover of $P^1$.

Comment: This is the question, By mistake I deleted it  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873614/modular-curve-g-galois-branched-cover

Comment: Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface and branched covering to $\mathbb P^1$ corresponds to meromorphic function on $M$. Since there are a lot of meromorphic function on $M$ I don't think there are any classification. @vikassrivastava